# Node Nodemon Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nodemon\bin\'

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i tried to execute server.js file using nodemon it is showing error.

C:\Users\gourav\WebstormProjects\Node.js-Register-Login-App-master>nodemon server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584

throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)

```
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)


at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)

at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
\
npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

npm ERR! node.js-register-login-app-master@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js`

npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin; ENOENT

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the node.js-register-login-app-master@1.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional

logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-

19T20_31_26_905Z-debug.log

Comment: have you installed nodemon globally to your npm version?

Comment: Did you install it with `npm install -g nodemon` (don't miss the -g ...) ?

Comment: Yes as the command u have said I tried to install but it is not getting installed. I have tried both locally as well as globally but not getting the result

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the path and delete everything with the name of nodemon,even within the folders, then install nodemon again globally. This worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I  did the below:

1. npx command ==> npm install -g nodemon
2. in package.json file ==>  "start": "nodemon server.js"
3. in terminal  used  ==> nodemon app.js (app.js is my root file here)

Answer (score 0):

```
Install npm gloabally by running this command 
npm install -g nodemon
if you are using linux then run below command 
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```